# Argument list too long: recursive header expansion failed react-native-fcm (React Native)

Tags: xcode, react-native

I'm facing such error "

> Argument list too long: recursive header expansion failed

" with 2 libraries with `react-native-fcm` and `react-native-fbsdk` in React Native project, any ideas how to fix that?

I saw that there was open issue in GitHub about that for [react-native-firebase](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/294), however, solutions which were there didn't help me.

Did anyone know the solution of that problem?

[image]

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

Comment: Did you fix this?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try removing all of the header search paths for the RCTFBSDK project (not your project). That worked for me.